# Android 3.1: Unit Testing a Class that Request User Permissions

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-permissions, android-mvp

I have a one button app that makes a phone call when pressed. The app uses MVP architecture. The logic to request the permission from a user to make a phone call was placed in the presenter (P) package.

Now, I'd like to setup a unit test that verifies that the class accurately requests the user permission to make a phone call yet I'm having issues getting started. There is an SO question: [Android Marshmallow: Test permissions with Espresso?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33929937/android-marshmallow-test-permissions-with-espresso/33935435) that attempts to address this problem stating one has to use UIAutomation and Espresso together. It's just not a clear enough answer to apply to this problem.

Can someone provide a solution to help setup this unit test?

**MainActivityPresenter class**

```
public class mainActivityPresenter {
    final int REQUEST_PHONE_CALL = 1;

    public void checkPhonePermissions(View view, MainActivity mainActivity){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mainActivity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},REQUEST_PHONE_CALL);
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check [GrantPermissionRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/GrantPermissionRule.html).Rule allows granting of runtime permissions on Android M (API 23) and above. Use this Rule when a test requires a runtime permission to do its work.

Comment: I'm running tests on Android (API 14). Is there a substitute for earlier Android SDK versions?

Comment: if your device API level under 23,you can use  adb shell pm grant "com.your.package" android.permission.your_permission

Comment: I don't see how testing the permission using shell commands is testing the mainActivityPresenter class? Couldn't we mock the "view" and "mainActivity" arguments to test if "mainActivityPresenter" class is working?